# Pandas: round a timedelta column to 15 secondes

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
     time1-high
0   18008 days 00:00:04
1   18008 days 00:00:11
2   18008 days 00:32:44
3   18008 days 01:16:19
4   18008 days 02:28:50
5   18008 days 02:30:37
6   18008 days 04:48:37
7   18008 days 09:57:19
8   18008 days 10:19:30
```

What I would like to have is the following:

```
         time1-high
    0   18008 days 00:00:15
    1   18008 days 00:00:15
    2   18008 days 00:32:45
    3   18008 days 01:16:30
    4   18008 days 02:29:00
    5   18008 days 02:30:45
    6   18008 days 04:48:45
    7   18008 days 09:57:30
    8   18008 days 10:19:30
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The idea would be to modify each seconds to the closest multiple of `15`. So in the first row `0   18008 days 00:00:04` it should be changed as `0   18008 days 00:00:15`, `4   18008 days 02:28:50` to `4   18008 days 02:29:00` etc... I am a bit stuck on that one. Is there a function that will automatically do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) with `15S`:

```
df['new1'] = df['time1-high'].dt.ceil(freq='15S') 
print (df)
           time1-high                new1
0 18008 days 00:00:04 18008 days 00:00:15
1 18008 days 00:00:11 18008 days 00:00:15
2 18008 days 00:32:44 18008 days 00:32:45
3 18008 days 01:16:19 18008 days 01:16:30
4 18008 days 02:28:50 18008 days 02:29:00
5 18008 days 02:30:37 18008 days 02:30:45
6 18008 days 04:48:37 18008 days 04:48:45
7 18008 days 09:57:19 18008 days 09:57:30
8 18008 days 10:19:30 18008 days 10:19:30
```